# syslog-daemon with dynamic facilitys or own logger for each software?

Tags: c++, linux, syslog

In the moment I'm writing a few daemon applications that produce output and this should be logged. So now I have two choices: Use syslog or provide own functions to write to my log file.

But I found a little problem and I think I am not the first one:
I don't like to provide my own functions to open the file, write to it, close it, etc. For one application it might be ok, but in my opinion an developer shouldn't write source code twice. So if you write two daemons - use the same log-functions, but there we are:

You COULD use the syslog of Linux, but I don't think it might be useful if all daemons write to facility "daemon" - I think that's old fashioned now! So I'd like to provide own facilities, but I didn't found an implementation of this yet. So are there any reasons for that?

I think there might be a reason that nobody did this before? So what should be the better way now? Write a "new" logging system or only a logger for my software?

Comment: Please reword to provide a clear question. You should avoid asking subjective questions (So I'm interested in your opinion).

http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Edited it now - sry :/

Comment: "... shouldn't write source code twice ..." - why not put your custom log functions into a (shared) library and link that to either daemon? I would consider logging only fatal/emergency errors into the syslog. Everything else (diagnostics, informational, etc.) I would log into an "application specific" log.

Answer (score 0):

The local0 to local7 syslog facilities are the way to go. Be sure to set APPNAME as a syslog field to be able to filter further the written logs.